# Highschool teachers based in Australia using Mathematica ?

Tags: education

Would like to make contact, I can supply my email.

thanks

Comment: Welcome!  Unfortunately, this Q&A site is strictly about specific aspects of  using *Mathematica*.  Perhaps you could find another online forum to ask your question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not, strictly speaking, a Wolfram Mathematica (or related product) question. This would be better suited to another site like [Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/).

Comment: This question would be very well suited for Wolfram Community I think.

Answer (score 4):

I think generally speaking this site is strictly used for questions related to the implementation of the code itself rather than all issues relating.

That said; Maybe this could give you a start in finding some teachers:
http://www.wolfram.com/training/special-event/hands-on-start-to-mathematica-victoria-mentors/

If you find some of the people that went on those courses either by contacting the speaker and asking them to forward your details, or checking out who shared it on facebook etc. you might have a few people to talk to, and they may be able to put you in touch with others.

Failing that, if you need any general advice, I have my teaching qualification and taught Physics in the UK for a year, and used Mathematica a couple of times for interactive lessons and as project aids and maybe be able to offer advice.

Hope that helps a little,
Nick